# Alert box generated with jquery not showing in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".confirm").on("click", function(event){
    if(confirm("Sind Sie sicher?")){
       return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

I am using this snippet to show an alert to select if you are sure or not, I tested it with firefox and chrome with win 7. But my client is using some kind of iMAC lap top and he tells me that he doesnt see the alert to select OK or CANCEL..

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7451950/1273830) might help! It seems you are gonna have to wrap the confirm call into another function.

Comment: I saw hairbos answer but this looks very odd, not sure yet if I understand whats wrong

Comment: FYI, you can simplify the body of the event handler to `return confirm("Sind Sie sicher?");`.